# printing the values of array with similar index

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a array :

```
 Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => Jagan ) [1] =>Array ( [username] => rahul ) ) )
```

now problem is both have index with name `username` so i can't access them simply by doing this

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $result=>$res)
{
   echo $res['username']);
}
?>
```

this will print both the usernames,i want to print them seperately.my concepts of arrays are little weak.

Comment: This prints both usernames because you're looping over all of the main array's contents, looking at each of the elements separately (those are arrays as well, each of them has a key 'username') and printing the 'username' value for each of them. What do you mean by 'print them separately'?

Comment: @anmolhans hope this will get to know what wrong.

Comment: print both seprately means,i want to print "username1" followed "username2" problem is username1 and username2 have both same key,username.

Answer (score 0):

The loop which you are trying to iterate will not give you expected result. This will loop only once. So in `$res` you will get this

```
Array(0 => Array("username" => "Jagan"), 1 => Array("username" => "rahul"))
```

and there is not index with name `username`

Change this to:

```
foreach ($results as $result=>$res)
```

**This:**

```
foreach ($results["results"] as $result=>$res)
```

**PHPcode:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$results = Array("results" => Array(0 => Array("username" => "Jagan"), 1 => Array("username" => "rahul")));
foreach ($results["results"] as $result => $res)
{
    echo $res['username'];
}
```